# How to implement const-object-specific constructors in C++?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, compiler-errors, constants

As an exercise I implemented a class called Array to simulate most of the functionalities of the class std::array. One thing I struggle to achieve is the following. Let's say we have the following declarations:

```
std::array<int,5> a1;
std::array<int,5> a1{};
const std::array<int,5> a1;
const std::array<int,5> a1{};
```

The third initialization shows an error:

`Default initialization of an object of const type 'const std::array<int, 5>' without a user-provided default constructor`

I want to achieve the same for the class I implemented but right now:

```
Array<int,5> a1;
Array<int,5> a1{};
const Array<int,5> a1;
const Array<int,5> a1{};
```

But, even the third initialization works since I only overridden the default constructor like this:

```
Array() = default;
```

I've seen some solutions online recommending using the:

```
Array() const = delete;
```

but this is also "syntaxly" incorrect. Const qualifier is not allowed on a constructor.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have nor need a (custom) constructor. It just has a public array member: `T some_name[N];`. This makes all the initialization syntax just work.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.  didn't know it was implemented that way.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what would be the best way around it, if it wasn't implemented that way? or is it not possible to achieve something like that

Comment: I'm not sure, might be impossible. Maybe there's some trick, but it's definitely not common knowledge.

Comment: @bhuseinovi1 Why do you think you need this behavior?

Comment: I do get an error for `const Array<int,5> a1;` https://godbolt.org/z/rEKEYvn5T

Comment: Show your code, We succeed to have error with [our implementaions](https://godbolt.org/z/695M4P5M7).

Answer (score 1):

It is generally impossible to have different initialization behavior between `const` and non-`const` objects. There is no way to overload constructors on that.

What you are showing with `std::array` is the only exception to the rule, which exists purely to make sure that the user doesn't accidentally default-initialize an object to an indeterminate state that can't ever be modified into a usable state (because of `const`), which is basically always a mistake.

You can find the rules for this exception e.g. at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization#Default_initialization_of_a_const_object). The exception applies if the type is not *const-default-constructible*.

The only way you can make your class type non-*const-default-constructible*, while still being *default-constructible*, is by

- relying on the implicit default constructor (by basically making your class aggregate) or by defaulting it as you showed, and
- intentionally having a member of the class that would be left in an indeterminate state by the defaulted default constructor (e.g. an `int` without a default initializer)

`std::array<int,5>` satisfies this because `std::array` is always aggregate and has an array of `int` as member which would be left in an indeterminate state by the implicit default constructor.

With e.g. `std::array<std::string, 5>` this `const` difference would not appear, because an array of `std::string` would not be left in an indeterminate state by the implicit default constructor.

There is normally no good reason to intentionally leave members uninitialized, so I do not recommend trying to go this route. This exceptional rule exists purely to *avoid* making the mistake of leaving something uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

No, objects are not `const` in their constructors or destructors because there is little a `const` constructor could do.